# Youtube video player issue

Tags: java, android, youtubeplayer

I'm trying to implement a youtube player in an application that will pull the video url from the mysql database.

First I added to gradle

```
//Android youtube player
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
```

After that I added to my activity

```
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.listeners.AbstractYouTubePlayerListener;
import com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView;
```

then

```
//youtube player
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
```

.

```
//youtube player
        setupYoutubePlayer();
```

.

```
private void setupYoutubePlayer() {
        youTubePlayerView = findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);
        getLifecycle().addObserver(youTubePlayerView);
    }
```

.

```
//if business has video_url show the layout  , else hide the view
        if (storeData.getVideo_url() != null && !storeData.getVideo_url().equals("null") && !storeData.getVideo_url().equals("")) {


            //show ad
            (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    youTubePlayerView.addYouTubePlayerListener(new AbstractYouTubePlayerListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReady(@NonNull YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
                            String videoId = AppHelper.extractYoutubeVideoId(storeData.getVideo_url());
                            if (videoId != null) youTubePlayer.cueVideo(videoId, 0);
                        }
                    });

                    findViewById(R.id.video_layout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }, 2000);


        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.video_layout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }


        //setup product variants
        setupServicesWidget();


        mViewManager.showContent();


    }
```

However, the video still does not play, it just stays in loading mode. I checked the database in the video url it says the correct url exampl. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Emyasd....

I would like your help! Thank you very much in advance.

Part from layout

```
<com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer.core.player.views.YouTubePlayerView
            android:id="@+id/youtube_player_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:autoPlay="false"/>
```

Comment: Anyone please...